# change attr of next('input') failing

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors, attr

I'm trying to set the next input in the dom to read only but am going wrong.

Heres the jQuery:

```
$('select.expense-code').change(function(e) {

    // If expense code is travel mileage
    if ($(this).val() == '5') {
        // Set miles to read only
        var currentRowAmount = $(e.target).next("input.amount");
        currentRowAmount.attr('readonly', true);
    }

});
```

Heres that part of the dom:

[image: DOM]

I've tried just setting the bg colour etc but nothing works, I'm sure its down to the .next() bit but need a prod in the right direction. Console.log() just gives you [].

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` grabs the immediate next sibling, it doesn't search for anything, the filter argument is just to make sure that the next sibling is within the filter.

from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, **it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.**

Since you already have id on the target, you can just do:

```
// current id ($(this).prop('id')) is Expense0ExpenseCode
var curId = $(this).prop('id');

// you are targetting Expense0Amount, which has the same Expense0 as the prefix
// so replace the suffix (ExpenseCode -> Amount):
var targetId = curId.replace('ExpenseCode', 'Amount');

// do the prop change
$('#' + targetId).prop('readonly', true);
```

The one liner:

```
$('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('ExpenseCode', 'Amount')).prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Could you explain what your doing there - struggling to follow and would like to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your elements aren't siblings at all, they are inside two different parent `.span1` elements :

```
$('select.expense-code').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == '5') {
        $(this).closest('.span1')
               .next('.span1')
               .find('input.amount')
               .prop('readonly', true);
    }
});
```